# How to customize the Xcode toolbar?

Tags: xcode, customization

When customizing the Xcode toolbar, am I pretty much limited by the buttons they give me in the Customize dialog?

I'd like to add actions like Step Over, Continue, Toggle Breakpoint, etc... but can't find a way to do so.  I tried dragging menu items to the toolbar a la Visual Studio, but to no avail.

Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have those buttons by default in the little bar above the text editor when running in debug mode. That being said i dont think you can customize that toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

Each window has its own set of customizable options. If you open the debugger window (in the Run menu) you will see a different set of toolbar icons than the main window. The debugger comes default with Step Over and Pause/Continue, but you can customize it in the same way.

Just explore a bit and find out where you should be looking for different options.

Comment: That's pretty cool. However, the problem is that I have to go to the trouble of opening the Debugger window when I all I want is to step through the code in the editor window.  Besides the Debugger window always breaks into assembly code, which is pointless to me at this point.  Is there a way to get the best of both worlds?

Answer (score 1):

With your Project window frontmost, choose View > Customize Toolbar.  Drag the items you want from the sheet directly into the window's toolbar.

Comment: The customize sheet does not have the icons I want, such as Step Over, Continue, etc...